# [A]Sales.ExtendedUserEntityMaster cannot be cast to [B]Sales.ExtendedUserEntityMaster

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

I got this error after replacing the dll (Sales) from bin folder in production. Once I restarted the IIS the issue gets resolved.

However, while replacing the dll, I had reset the IIS. Not sure why this error has come and restart iis has resolved this?

Comment: IIS won't refresh worker process when you replace the dill file. Which means the request are probably still being handled by old worker process because stop site may not kill the worker process immediately. However, when you reset IIS, the whole application pool get refreshed and I think that the might be the reason.

Comment: Thanks, Jokies. But after replacing the dlls I had restart the IIS manually so it should have refresh the worker process right?

Comment: Have you seen the PID get changed after replacing the dll and restart IIS? Did you restart IIS by net stop/start or IISRESET? Based on my understanding these operations will refresh all IIS service and application pool. So I think either the worker process not being recycled or any IIS service get updated. If you need to find the root cause, we may need more information about system IO and stack trace.

Comment: Sometimes I stop the sites, replace the dlls and then start the sites. Not using reset command. Could it also be a reason which causes this issue?

Comment: Nope, I haven't checked the PID gets changed or not. but I can share the logs if you want. Does IIS logs help you? Also, I would appreciate you could explain to me this issue in detail and how old worker process causing this.

Comment: Restart IIS will refresh site configuration and application pool. Since dll should be loaded in asp.net pipeline. I think this issue could only happen in old app pool. So please check whether app pool get refreshed after replacing dll.